# How to redirect save button

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

How to redirect save button to a Managed Installed visual force page. In UI Page, when save button is clicked it opens a popup window of installed managed vf page in it after selecting the options record will be saved. I am looking for the same operation on a visualforce page

Comment: Where is the Save button you're referring to? On most pages, clicking Save does not open a popup window. Please clarify the context for your question.

Comment: Please provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new controller class which inherits the controller class for that page, and then override the Save() function to go to which ever page you want to redirect to. Another option is if you have control over the destination page, on the Page_Load event, you can test the ApexPage object to determine which page the user just came from, and if it's that page, then redirect them to the page you want to redirect them to.

Please let us know if this works. Thanks